# SVN plugin for Windows Explorer

Tags: svn, windows-xp, windows-explorer

Is there any application which would integrate with Windows Explorer and show SVN properties of selected item (directory or file) in the left pane of explorer, let's say below "Details" box?

It would be convenient.

**EDIT:** I am looking for the exact functionality I explained above, not just any GUI svn client.

Answer (score 12):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Well, it shows only status as an icon overlay.

Comment: http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html - i'm not sure if there's a free edition

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I know about TortoiseSVN, but I am looking for the exact functionality I explained above, not just any GUI svn client.

Answer (score 2):

[Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) has great SVN/Explorer integration, though I'm unsure about the left pane.

Answer (score 1):

[tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is great.
http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

This gives you buttons in Windows Explorer http://blog.oxfordcc.co.uk/tortoisesvn-integrated-into-windows-7-libraries/ or something like http://www.wandisco.com/smartsvn/home may go some of the way to providing the kind of quick access to information you want